# MySQL/Php: nonrepeating random selection with unique ID selectors

Tags: php, mysql, random, selector

I'm new to using php and mysqp. 
Using the code below, I am calling and echoing four names from a mysql database (in a 'names' column) without repeat.
However, what I'd like to do is assign a unique CSS id selector to each name. 
The intent is to have four individually styled boxes around the page, each with a different name chosen randomly upon load.

What would be the best code to do this?
(Fyi I am using an xxamp installation.)
Thanks!

```
<?php

$sandbox = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password")
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("sandbox", $sandbox);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $sandbox);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
$name1 = $row['Name'];
echo $name1 . '<br>' ;
}
```

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (`mysql_*` functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (`mysqli_*` functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into learning about that. In the short term, does it have any direct bearing on the question?

Comment: Can you give a little more information as to what you are trying to do? For example, why cant you do this: echo <div id="$name1">"$name1"</div>;

Comment: not sure I follow your question about my question, actually. My goal is to pull four names at random (without repeat) from the table and put each in a div with a unique ID.

However I have tried several variations on the line you suggest, and not yet found code that works to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you:

```
<?php

$sandbox = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password")
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("sandbox", $sandbox);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY RAND() GROUP BY Name LIMIT 4";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $sandbox);

$i = 0; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) { 
echo '<div id=box"'.$i++.'">'.$row['Name'].'</div>'; 
}
```

This gives you an unique CSS selector using the primary key in your table?

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
$sandbox = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password")
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("sandbox", $sandbox);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $sandbox);

$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
$id = $row['ID'];
echo '<div id=box"'.$i++.'">your content</div>';
}
```

Comment: How is this constructive and providing any different answer from what was already there?

Comment: `$i = 0;` is not required.

Comment: @TeodorTalov- Sorry, had this page open for awhile and must've constructed an answer after yours without checking.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid- please explain why it's not required? how is initializing a variable to be used as a counter not required?